# Sourcecode for Paymentroll example in Robert C. Martin book

Tags: visual-studio

Throughout the book "Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#" by Robert C. Martin  a small Paymentroll application is build. While most of the source code is printed in place, some classes are missing and some are incomplete. The book says on the firest page:

> The book includes many source code examples that are also available for download from the
>   authors' Web site.

Unfortunately this seems to be a lie. Unless either [this](http://www.objectmentor.com/omTeam/martin_r.html) is not the author's website (the book forgets to mention the authors website adress) or I am blind.

Does anyone have the comlete source code for that book preferably in form of a Visual Studio project or knows where I can find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Object Mentor is indeed the official website for Bob Martin, and hosts the download for that book here: http://www.objectmentor.com/PPP/ and here: https://github.com/unclebob/PPP

FYI, you can contact Bob via Twitter (he uses it quite prolifically): http://twitter.com/unclebobmartin or through Object Mentor, which is Bob's very small group, using the methods on this page: http://objectmentor.com/omCompany/omi_contact.html